# issues with loading images in custom control

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I am new to the WP7 platform and I am facing something strange, I have a custom component that has an image. (Part of the custom component below)

```
<Rectangle x:Name="ImageForeground" Height="240" Width="240" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                DataContext="{TemplateBinding Image}"
                OpacityMask="{Binding Converter={StaticResource brushConverter}}" />
```

Here is the brushConverter

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        BitmapImage image = (BitmapImage)value;
        ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
        if (image != null)
        {
            imageBrush.ImageSource = image;
        }
        return imageBrush;
    }
```

Now i add the custom component to a page with

```
<rounded:RoundedImageView Image="/Images/image1.png"/>
```

Here comes the weird part. The component only displays certain png images!! I have 5 all in all, with ALL their Build Action properties set to Content. But the control only loads some and not all. Even stranger is if i put the images in a regular Image component like so

```
<Image Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,17,0,0" Name="image3" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Source="/Images/service_reload.png" />
```

It works!!! WTF!!

Any ideas?!

Comment: Solved:
I attached the brushConverter binding to the Fill property of the Rectangle instead of the OpacityMask property and it worked like a charm

`<Rectangle x:Name="ImageForeground" Height="240" Width="240" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    DataContext="{TemplateBinding Image}"  Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource brushConverter}}"
                    />`

Comment: Just wondering - why would you use a Rectangle instead of an image?

Comment: @CoolDude - You can post your comment as an answer and accept it in a couple of days.

Comment: @xyzzer I'm using it cos I need the rounded edges of the rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
Solved: I attached the brushConverter binding to the Fill property of the Rectangle instead of the OpacityMask property and it worked like a charm

```
 <Rectangle x:Name="ImageForeground" Height="240" Width="240" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" DataContext="{TemplateBinding Image}" Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource brushConverter}}" />
```